# Use return of method in another class in C#

Tags: c#, class, return

First of all, I'm new in C# (and in development overall). My question is quiet simple.

I've two different classes. A method of one of my class is returning an array. I'm trying to use this array in a method of the other class, here is the code:

The idea here is to retrieve those numbers stored in the array, and generate cards with related ID (stored in DB) in the `for` statement.

```
class c_random
{
    int nbr_random_to_generate = 2; // number to generate

    /*
     * This function 
     *  - execute the methods to counts nbr of cards in DB
     *  - Create an Array with id of cards to generate
     *  */
    public int[] generate_random()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        c_ConnectionMySQL obj_sqlRes = new c_ConnectionMySQL(); // Create a connection to MySQL
        obj_sqlRes.count_cards_DB(); // Execute the method to count the number of cards in DB
        Console.WriteLine(obj_sqlRes.nbr_cards);


        int[] array_random = new int[nbr_random_to_generate];
        for (int i = 0; i < nbr_random_to_generate; i++)
        {
            array_random[i] = rnd.Next(obj_sqlRes.nbr_cards); // generate an array of x (nbr_random_to_generate), with the count of cards as limit
        }
        return array_random;
    }
}


class c_Hand
{
    // ATTRIBUTES
    int nbr_in_hand;

    

    // METHODS
    public void HandGeneration(int a)
    {

        int a;
        c_ConnectionMySQL countCards = new c_ConnectionMySQL();
        countCards.count_cards_DB();

        c_card hand = new c_card();
        c_random rnd = new c_random();

        rnd.generate_random();


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            /*/
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `rnd.generate_random();` you're not doing anything with the result.

Comment: I'm confused, what's the question here? "How do I assign the result of a method to a variable?" You already have an example of you doing that with `c_card hand = new c_card();` (yes that's a method you're calling) and `array_random[i] = rnd.Next(obj_sqlRes.nbr_cards);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the return of `generate_random()` to a variable when it is called.

`int[] array = rnd.generate_random();`

Comment: Allright many thanks, that was the point. So basically, I've to create a new variable (here an array of course), to store the return of the method. Make sens. Many thanks for your answer!